# Static C++ library linked to C# code

Tags: c#, c++, dll, static-libraries

I am trying to link a C++ library to a C# code. I found this very good explanation in this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/299da822-5539-4e5b-9ba7-b614e564c9f4/presenting-a-c-library-lib-for-use-in-c-project?forum=vcgeneral

So I tried to reproduce it here:

My header:

```
// Static Library's Header: MathFuncsLib.h

namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b
        static double Add(double a, double b);

        // Returns a - b
        static double Subtract(double a, double b);

        // Returns a * b
        static double Multiply(double a, double b);

        // Returns a / b
        static double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

My C++ source is:

```
/* MathFuncsLib.cpp
   compile with: cl /c /EHsc MathFuncsLib.cpp
   post-build command: lib MathFuncsLib.obj

    This example comes from MSDN  
*/

#include "MathFuncsLib.h"

#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

and finally, my C# code which I want to use the C++ library is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestCppLibrary
{
    public class Program
    {
        [DllImport("MathFuncsLib.dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern double Add(double a, double b);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a = 7.4;
            double b = 99.3;
            double res = Add(a, b);
            Console.WriteLine("The sum is : " + res.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> {"Unable to load DLL 'MathFuncsLib.dll': The specified module
>   could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}

I already spent 2 days searching a solution for this, but I couldn´t find a helpful answer.

I guess I need to define my library as a COM. If so, how to do that? Anyways, how can I link my library to the C# code in this case?

Thank you

Henrique

Comment: Are you using CLR? It makes this much easier, no PInvoke requeired, just add the DLL as a reference. Also this: "MathFuncsLib.dll.dll", double .dll?

Comment: I can't use CLR. Can I make a C++ library that doesn’t depend on MSVC C++ runtime? Is that possible?

Comment: Is your DLL actually named `MathFuncsLib.dll.dll`? And if so, is it in the same folder as the C# exe?

Comment: That link shows three different ways to do this: COM, P/Invoke, and C++/CLI. Did you try to follow the steps of one of those ways?

Comment: Sorry @crashmstr , when I copied my code here  the "dll" duplicated. Actually it  is MathFuncsLib.dll and it is located in a folder into my solution where is also my C# project.

Comment: For P/Invoke to work your C++ functions need to be `extern "C"` and not be members of a class. Also, double .dll extension like others pointed out.

Comment: Thanks @crashmstr. I tried them, I can build the library in all the cases, but it did´t link to my C# code. For example, for the first way, using COM, my dll is not listed as COM object. I didn´t find how to generate COM from C++ static library.

Comment: Thanks @LucasTrzesniewski. I will try to use extern "C", but isn´t it related to dynamic libraries?

Comment: That link does not show all the code needed. You need to start a *new* project that is COM to do way #1, then have it link to the static library and expose COM methods that call the static library.

Comment: @crashmstr. Got it! Thank you! So from this new COM project I will be able to use as reference my library in the C# project, right?

Comment: @HenriqueAmaral yes, once you create a new COM project, link in the existing static library, create COM methods that call the functions in the static library, then you can add a reference to your COM dll in your C# project.

Comment: You are not getting helpful comments, it is just a simple file-not-found error.  With a very simple explanation: C++ projects build to a different directory than C# projects.  The native DLL end up in the solution's Debug directory, your C# program's exe file ends up in the project's bin\Debug directory   Have a look-see with Explorer.  So if inevitably falls over because it can't find the DLL.  The simplest fix: Project > Properties > Build tab > Output path setting, change it to `..\Debug`

Comment: @HansPassant thank you very much for your help. Yes, these comments has helped me a lot. That is my first time linking  C++ to C#. These datails you and crashmstr gave me sometimes are not clear in the documentation and tutorials. Thank you again. I feel I am getting closer.

Comment: @HansPassant, you comment solve my problem related to the location of the dll fila. Now I am getting this error <pre> 
Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) </pre>. It seems to be related to the fact that my C++ library is Win32 and my C# solution is in x64. I guess I need to build my library as x64, Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by  building my C# solution as x86 (Properties -> Build ->  Plataform Target -> x86). Also I changed my code a  bit cause I was getting an error related to the entry point. Should I edit my original post or share my functional code here? Thank you all guys for help me out with this.